# passing username:password in gitlab url not working

Tags: gitlab

git clone https://username:password@gitlab/username/example.git not working

should I need to pass token for authentication.

Comment: pass token is not essential. can you post the error log?

Comment: fatal: repository  0
down vote
favorite

git clone https://username:password@gitlab/username/example.git not found.

Comment: I think username and password will work.